# Making element invisible while delay function is working

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I want elements to appear one by one on the page with an animation. I created the animation but I don’t know how to **hide** (not `display: none`) the element while delay function is in use.

So, after 1 second, element appears with `appear` animation, however there must be something else to hide it before animation starts.

```
.insta {
  animation: appear 0.4s linear 1s; 
}
@keyframes appear {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(30%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}
```

```
<p class=«insta»>Instagram</p>
```

Comment: If I am understanding the question correctly, you want animation-fill-mode. Add following two properties to your css -> opacity:0 property; animation-fill-mode: forwards;

Answer (score 0):

Set opacity: 0. That hides your text. Using animation-fill-mode: forwards will let you have the properties added at the end of the animation.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by adding an `animation-fill-mode: both;` to your CSS. That means that the browser will apply the animation's first frame until it starts, and its last frame after it has finished.

Since your animation starts with `opacity: 0;` and ends with `opacity: 1;`, no further modifications required.

You can also combine it into the `animation` property (just add a `both` keyword somewhere):

```css
.insta {
  animation: appear 0.4s linear 1s both;
}

@keyframes appear {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(30%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="insta">Instagram</p>
```

Try on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/FZs111/pen/VwvVRPG) (at least until the Stack Snippets server is down...)